# How to fix Google Analytics Experiments code?

Tags: testing, google-analytics, google-experiments

```
function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var
k='code-here',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
if(l.search.indexOf('utm_expid='+k)>0)return;
function f(n){if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.
indexOf(';',i);return escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c.
length:j))}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;d.write(
'<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':
'://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?'+'utmxkey='+k+
'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date().
valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})();
```

The code above is my code given by google analytics to track a/b test. I got this error when validade the code

> Original: Possibly broken experiment code found here: line:4,
>   column:5.

Comment: What did you use to validate  (seeing that this does not seem to be one the list here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2364634?hl=en) ? When I paste this code into a javascript console it produces no errors - are you sure that this is exactly what's on your webpage  ?

Comment: at the google analytics experiments I have a "validate". When I try to validate it gets an error. By the way I  check it with lint and it seems ok.

Comment: This is just a guess, but lines 4 and 5 both end with "c.," so you might try breaking those lines after the "c.indexOf(" and "c.length," respectively.